# NSNumberFormatter trucates leading 0's

Tags: ios, objective-c, locale, nsnumberformatter

I have written a function to convert a number from arabic numerals to digits. I have used `NSNumberFormatter`for this. But the problem is the number caqn start with a zero and `NSNumberFormatter` truncates the leading zero. I need this value as I have to do a comparison. The number might not start with zero always. So I cannot put any other condition. Pleaes help me if anyone has a solution. Thank you.

My code is:

```
-(NSString*)convertNumberFromArabic:(NSString*)numberToConvert{
    NSNumberFormatter *nf1 = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    NSLocale *locale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en"];
    [nf1 setLocale:locale];

    NSNumber *newNum = [nf1 numberFromString:numberToConvert];

    NSString *reverseConvert = [nf1 stringFromNumber:newNum];

    return reverseConvert;
}
```

Comment: Could you give an example of sample input and desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a bit confusing. You say you want to "convert a number **from** arabic numerals to digits", but your method name says **to** Arabic. I have written the method to convert from Arabic to Latin. If you want to got the other way, you just change the `YES` to `NO`.

Here's the code:

```
-(NSString*)convertArabicDigitsToLatin:(NSString*)numberToConvert{
    NSMutableString* result = [numberToConvert mutableCopy];
    CFRange range = CFRangeMake(0, result.length);
    CFStringTransform((__bridge CFMutableStringRef)result, &range, kCFStringTransformLatinArabic, YES);
    return result;
}
```

This doesn't interpret the string as a number, it just transliterates the Arabic digits as string characters to Latin digits.